# Why this repeats the same random number?

Tags: go, random

I'm new to Go and not sure why it prints the same number for `rand.Intn(n int) int` for every run:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)


func main() {
    fmt.Println(rand.Intn(10)) 
}
```

The docs says :

> Intn returns, as an int, a non-negative pseudo-random number in [0,n) from the default Source. It panics if n <= 0.

And how do I properly seed the random number generation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By calling the [`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) function, passing it a (random) seed (typically the current unix timestamp). Quoting from [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) package doc:

> Top-level functions, such as Float64 and Int, use a default shared Source that produces a deterministic sequence of values each time a program is run. Use the Seed function to initialize the default Source if different behavior is required for each run.

Example:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

If `rand.Seed()` is not called, the generator behaves as if seeded by 1:

> Seed uses the provided seed value to initialize the default Source to a deterministic state. If Seed is not called, the generator behaves as if seeded by Seed(1).

Comment: Thanks @icza. So the default `seed` is some constant ?

Comment: why would a function exist that is named "rand" when it does not do anything random, unless a second function is being called? What would be the use-case of not wanting to have a random number each time? E.g. why are both functionalities not combined by default?

Comment: @lifeofguenter Because this gives you the possibility to repeat, to "replay" the same pseudo-random sequence of numbers (by using the same seed at the beginning of the operation). That's a useful property.

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import

(
"fmt"
"math/rand"
"time"
)

func randomGen(min, max int) int {
rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
return rand.Intn(max - min) + min
}

func main() {
randNum := randomGen(1, 10)
fmt.Println(randNum)
}
```

Comment: Do *not* re-seed on every call.

Comment: @elcomendaante: This is the reason you should not seed it each call. Do change your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636859/random-number-generator-why-seed-every-time

Answer (score -1):

Under the package, *math/rand*, you can find a **type Rand**.

> func New(src Source) *Rand  -  New returns a new Rand that uses random
>   values from src to generate other random values.

It actually needs a seed to generate it.

1. step 1: create a seed as a source using new Source.
   time.Now().UnixNano() is used for the accuracy.
2. step 2: create a
   *type Rand* from the seed
3. step 3: generate a random number.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)   

func main() {  
    source := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())    
    r := rand.New(source)    
    fmt.Println(r.Intn(100))    
}
```