# Why "using sleep()" makes the result of the same code being different?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that create a string array which contains random strings, and the `rand_str()` is to make a string of 20 length long. When I use `sleep()`, the result is exactly what I want. However, I think `sleep()` shouldn't appear in my code. Removing `sleep()`, the random strings created are totally different. I am really confused about this. Could someone help to explain why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <array>
#define show(w) for(auto val:w){cout<<val<< " ";}cout<<endl;
using namespace std;

char *rand_str(char *str,const int len);

int main(){
    const int len = 10;
    char *a[len];
    string c[len];
    array<string,len> ar;char b[len][21];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        ar[i] = rand_str(b[i], 21);
        fflush(stdin);
//      Sleep(1000);
    }
    show(ar);
    return 0;
}
char *rand_str(char *str,const int len){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;++i)
    {
        switch((rand()%3))
        {
            case 1:
                str[i]='A'+rand()%26;
                break;
            case 2:
                str[i]='a'+rand()%26;
                break;
            default:
                str[i]='0'+rand()%10;
                break;
        }
    }
    str[len - 1]='\0';
    return str;
}
```

Not using sleep() :

[image]

Using sleep() :

[image]

Comment: Please include the code in the question. Links can break and images cannot be compiled, hence code is always prefered

Comment: Sorry I'm new here~

Comment: You need to provide enough code for us to reproduce the issue, or at least compile your code: we don't know what `rand_str` does, so we cannot work out what kind of interactions might be causing this behavior.

Comment: Use /dev/random in Linux or look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand

Comment: `/dev/random` is not portable. And sometimes you don't want truly random numbers. Controlling the seed lets you re-run the program with the same "random"-number, which makes debugging much easier.

Answer (score 3):

The program you've written executes quickly enough that it is extremely likely that every single loop of `rand_str` will occur in the span of a single second. This is important because your method for generating strings involves calls to `time`, because `time` returns a `time_t` object, which is specified in the C-standard as:

> The encoding of calendar time in time_t is unspecified, but most systems conform to POSIX specification and return **a value of integral type holding the number of seconds since the Epoch**. Implementations in which time_t is a 32-bit signed integer (many historical implementations) fail in the year 2038.
>
> —**`time`**, [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time)

So if the entire program executes in under a second, every single call to `time` in that span will return the same value, seeding your random numbers with the same value each time, and producing identical output on each loop. Conversely, when you `Sleep` for 1000 milliseconds (1 second), you nearly guarantee that each execution will have a different seed, and thus different output.

In general, you should only seed the random numbers once, at the start of your program. Alternatively, you should consider leaning how to use the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library, since it contains far better mechanisms for generating Random Numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`rand_str` most likely has some kind of time-dependence associated with it. The one you present has a *seed* set to `srand(time(NULL));` so it certainly does.

And `Sleep(1000)` (which will be a *minimum* sleep of 1000 units) is enough to change the result.

Removing the sleep call and your program execution is fast enough for the time-dependence of `rand_str` to be unobservable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rand_str` function re-seeds the PRNG *on every single call*, and it does so using the *current time in seconds*. It then pulls out the "first" number in that sequence and returns it.

That means you only get a different pseudo-random sequence for function calls for different seconds in time. If you make multiple function calls within the same second, you keep re-seeding with the same seed, which results in the same sequence, and the first number in that same sequence is the same number always returned. That's why the sleep makes a difference: it changes the seed.

You should [only seed *once*, at the start of your program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322995/560648), then just [use the resulting sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20636859/560648) as needed.

Incidentally, this entire methodology is outdated. Since C++11, [we do random numbers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665818/560648).

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely due to the fact that computers cannot produce truly random numbers.
Hence, there exists a concept called a `seed`. And the most common `seed` for pseudo-random number generation is the time.
Making your program wait a bit will make it run the random generator with a different seed.

Comment: Are u suggesting that  the random number generated in 1 ms  is all the same due to the seed?

Comment: @Merediii That's exactly correct, but it's the fault of your code, not of the random number generator. You didn't have to use time as seed, you didn't have to use _seconds-resolution_ time as seed, and you didn't have to seed over and over again. :)

Comment: Looking at `rand_str()` this is exactly what it is going on. The function uses the time to initialize the seed in the start of the function. But since the function is restarted many times in a short time span. The clock will have no time to advance so you will always seed with the same value and get the same pseudo-random numbers. (The resolution of `time()` is typically 1 second). The correct solution is to call `srand()` *once* at the start of your program.

Comment: "computers cannot produce truly random numbers" Yes they can with special hardware although at the time of writing they are extremely slow cf. a pseudo generator.